# Content in Google Chrome larger than 16777216 px not being rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I recently discovered that my content in google chrome was not being rendered when it was longer than 16777216px in length.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2wH/965/)

FULL HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content {
    height: 16777316px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#semi-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#hidden {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">Scroll Down &darr;
  <div id="semi-hidden"> The Bottom 100px of this DIV is not rendered. </div>
  <div id="hidden"> This DIV is completly hidden. </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: This is due to Google Chrome not supporting layouts larger than 16777216 px.

Comment: Maybe because that's ridiculously long? On a 60dpi monitor that's over FOUR MILES long

Comment: It may be significant to note that the number you found is suspiciously close to 16,777,216, which is 2²⁴.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome represents laid out element positions using LayoutUnits, which can represent 1/64th the space of a signed int (2^31 / 64 integral values, or +/-16777216).

Google Chrome has no intention of supporting larger values in the near future.

[Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401762)